# purrr list evaluation strangeness

Tags: r, purrr

It seems that purrr functions evaluate differently if lists have titles or not, but why? Is this just "one of those things"?

Example:

```
func_b <- function(x,y,z) paste(x,y,z)

## Works as expected
pmap(list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length), func_b) %>% head(2)
```

> [[1]] [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
>
> [[2]] [1] "4.9 3 1.4"

```
## Doesn't work
pmap(map(iris[,1:3],list),func_b)
```

> Error in .f(Sepal.Length = .l[[c(1L, 1L)]], Sepal.Width = .l[[c(2L, 1L)]], : unused arguments (Sepal.Length = .l[[c(1, 1)]], Sepal.Width = .l[[c(2, 1)]], Petal.Length = .l[[c(3, 1)]])

But the only difference seems to be that one of the lists retains its titles while the other one doesn't?

```
list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length) %>% map(head)
```

> [[1]] [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
>
> [[2]] [1] 3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
>
> [[3]] [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7

```
as.list(iris[,1:3]) %>% map(head)
```

> $Sepal.Length [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
>
> $Sepal.Width [1] 3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
>
> $Petal.Length [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7

```
class(list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length)) == class(as.list(iris[,1:3]))
```

> [1] TRUE

```
str(list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length)); str(as.list(iris[,1:3]))

List of 3
 $ : num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ : num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
List of 3
 $ Sepal.Length: num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
```

If we just get rid of the names of the second list, it works without a problem.

```
aa <- as.list(iris[,1:3]) 
names(aa) <- NULL      
pmap(aa,func_b) %>% head(2)
```

> [[1]]
>   [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
>
> [[2]]
>   [1] "4.9 3 1.4"

So my specific question: WHY do the titles affect the evaluation method? Is there any way to convert things without breaking the dplyr pipe to eliminate the names?

Comment: Unnamed lists are assigned to the function arguments by position, named lists by name. That means `purrr` is trying to do `func_b(Sepal.Length = ....., etc)`. You can always pipe into `unname` if necessary.

Comment: Nice, the unname works beautifully: `map(iris[,1:3],list) %>% unname() %>% pmap(func_b) %>% map(head)`

Comment: relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122773/harnessing-f-list-names-with-purrrpmap/51123520#51123520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Axeman is spot-on but you can defensibly & dynamically program around it:

```
library(purrr)

func_b <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  paste(args[[1]], args[[2]], args[[3]])
}

list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length) %>%
  pmap(func_b) %>%
  head(2)
## [[1]]
## [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "4.9 3 1.4"

iris[,1:3] %>% pmap(func_b) %>% head(3)
## [[1]]
## [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "4.9 3 1.4"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "4.7 3.2 1.3"

func_c <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  paste0(args, collapse = " ")
}

list(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Petal.Length) %>%
  pmap(func_c) %>%
  head(2)
## [[1]]
## [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "4.9 3 1.4"

iris[,1:3] %>% pmap(func_c) %>% head(3)
## [[1]]
## [1] "5.1 3.5 1.4"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "4.9 3 1.4"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "4.7 3.2 1.3"

iris[,1:2] %>% pmap(func_c) %>% head(3)
## [[1]]
## [1] "5.1 3.5"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "4.9 3"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "4.7 3.2"
```

Comment: so you are basically explicitly making the list unnamed in the function itself, which protects you from nomatter what list type is sent, is this correct?

Comment: aye. correct. and tried to make it generic for any `pmap()` call