# Harnessing .f list names with purrr::pmap

Tags: r, purrr

The following works ok:

```
pmap_dbl(iris, ~ ..1 + ..2 + ..3 + ..4)
```

The documentation for `.l` provides for `A list of lists. ... List names will be used if present.`.  This suggests you should be able to work with the list names (i.e. column names). However:

```
pmap_dbl(iris, ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width)
Error in .f(Sepal.Length = .l[[c(1L, i)]], Sepal.Width = .l[[c(2L, i)]],  : 
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

How are list names harnessed in practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The formula argument `~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width` is passed to `purrr::as_mapper`.

```
purrr::as_mapper(~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width)
# function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
# Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
```

You can see that there's no direct way for this function to know what these variables are.

I can think of 3 ways around this. I'll use @zacdav's example as it's more compact and readable than yours:

```
named_list <- list(one = c(1, 1),
                   two = c(2, 2),
                   three = c(3, 3))
```

---

**Explicit definition**

You can define explicitly these variables as shown in @zacdav's answer it will work.

---

**Explore the dots argument**

There is a way to access the named arguments through the `...` parameter of the function returned by `as_mapper`.

The arguments of the function are named when names are available, as the doc states in other words.

That explains why `pmap(named_list, function(x,y,z) x+y+z)` will fail with error:

> unused arguments (one = .l[[c(1, i)]], two = .l[[c(2, i)]], three = .l[[c(3, i)]])

See:

```
pmap(named_list, ~names(list(...)))
# [[1]]
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "one"   "two"   "three"
```

(`pmap(unname(named_list), function(x,y,z) x+y+z)` on the other hand will work fine)

So this will work:

```
pmap(named_list, ~ with(list(...), one + two + three))
# [[1]]
# [1] 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 6
```

---

**Use pryr::f**

`pryr` offers a neat shortcut for function definitions with `pryr::f` :

```
library(pryr)
f(one + two + three)
# function (one, three, two) 
# one + two + three

pmap(named_list, f(one + two + three))
# [[1]]
# [1] 6
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 6
#
```

Be careful however when using it, global variables will still show up as parameters and functions will or will not be included in parameters depending on how they're called. For example :

```
x <- 1
test <- mean
f(test(x) + lapply(iris,test2))
# function (iris, test2, x) 
# test(x) + lapply(iris, test2)
```

So it's not a general approach and you should use it only with simple cases. the second approach, though a bit of a hack, will be general.

Moreover `f` is ordering the parameters alphabetically, this should not be an issue when dealing with a named list, but be careful when dealing with partially named lists.

Comment: This is clearly the tidy approach. Never come across `pryr` so thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
library(purrr)
named_list <- list(one = c(1, 1),
                   two = c(2, 2),
                   three = c(3, 3))

pmap(named_list, function(one, two, three) one + two + three)
```

Or even in the `pmap` documentation:

```
# Matching arguments by name
l <- list(a = x, b = y, c = z)
pmap(l, function(c, b, a) a / (b + c))
```

This works because it expects to see each named element apparently.

```
pmap_dbl(iris, function(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species) Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
```

You can also make use of `...` it seems:

```
pmap_dbl(iris, function(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, ...) Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)
```

ideally this example would just use `rowSums` in practice though.

Comment: Thanks. Good if we can work with the reproducible example rather than quote documentation

Comment: E.g. this fails `pmap_dbl(as.list(iris), function(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)` with `unused arguments` error

Comment: Your example fails because the function expects all names in the list to appear, you don't need to use them all.

Comment: `pmap_dbl(as.list(select(iris, -Species)), ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width)` returns `object 'Sepal.Length' not found`

Comment: You have to use a function. As per the documentation.

Comment: I am curious as to the context of what you want to do though - does seem like there is a much easier answer.

Comment: Just wondering how list names are supposed to be harnessed. It feels like it should be the tidy approach to combine `~` with list names. Perhaps that will come soon.

Comment: I just discovered this works: `pmap_dbl(as.list(iris), function(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, ...) Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)`

Comment: The `as.list` you use in your examples are unnecessary

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yea it is - I just copied his code. But I'll remove it.